# page doesn’t seem to exist Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

my main page doesn’t seem to be viewed on my site but other pages are working.

l have tried saving permalinks, clearing cache but still nothing on a different browser it’s saying redirected too many times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see the “too many redirects” error is because your website has been set up in a way that keeps redirecting it between different web addresses. When your browser tries to load your site, it goes back and forth between those web addresses in a way that will never complete — a redirect loop.

Source: [Too Many Redirects Error](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/too-many-redirects-error#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20you%20see%20the,never%20complete%20%E2%80%94%20a%20redirect%20loop.)

Try to fix this loop and see if it works correctly.